# My code with regular expressions for file doesn't run properly

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    regex r1("(.*\\blecture\\b.*)");
    regex r2("(.* practice.*)");
    regex r3("(.* laboratory practice.*)");
    smatch base_match;
    int lecture = 0;
    int prakt = 0;
    int lab = 0;
    string name = "schedule.txt";
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(name);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "didint open ";
    }
    else {
        string str;
        while (!fin.eof()) {
            str = "";
            getline(fin, str);
            cout << str << endl;

            if (regex_match(str, base_match, r1)) {
                lecture++;
            }
            if (regex_match(str, base_match, r2)) {
                prakt++;
            }
            if (regex_match(str, base_match, r3)) {
                lab++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The number of lectures: " << lecture << "\n";
    cout << "The number of practices: " << prakt << "\n";
    cout << "[The number of laboratory work][1]: " << lab << "\n";

    fin.close();
}
```

[image]

In this program, I need to count the number of lectures, practice and laboratory work per week using regular expressions. I have got a text file, which you can see on the screen. But for lectures and practice, it doesn't work right.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2I0.png)

Comment: OT: `while (!fin.eof()) {  str = ""; getline(fin, str);` its better to write `while (getline(fin, str)) {`

Comment: you did't count how many words in a same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the number of times each regex matches. C++ has `std::sregex_iterator` for performing multiple regex matches over a string.
That means you can do the following:

```
for (auto it = std::sregex_iterator{str.cbegin(), str.cend(), r1}; it != std::sregex_iterator{}; it++) {
  lecture++;
}
```

If you want to get really fancy you can even do it in one go:

```
auto it = std::sregex_iterator{str.cbegin(), str.cend(), r1};
lecture += std::distance(it, std::sregex_iterator{});
```

Alternatively, you can call `std::regex_search` several times, starting from the end offset of the previous match (or 0 for the first).

EDIT: as remarked in the comments, this assumes that your regexes are suitable to incremental matching. Yours eat the whole string (presumably because `regex_match` is anchored whereas `regex_search/regex_iterator` are not), so you need to at least change your regular expression definitions to the following:

```
regex r1("\\blecture\\b");
regex r2(" practice");
regex r3(" laboratory practice");
```

... and of course every match for r3 is also a match for r2, but I leave that for you.

Comment: Do I need to include any library? Because I have mistakes in "it" and "sregex_iterator" . And thank you

Comment: I typo'd the second `str` as `std` in both examples. fixed

Comment: I changed it, but it still shows mistakes(also reduced std, as i used namespace std)

Comment: No, this is plain C++17 code.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I'm desperate. I changed my code with your edits, got some warnings and the same result(I added screenshot to my question)

Comment: oh, duh. because your regular expressions eat the whole string. `r1` should be just `"\\blecture\\b"` (without the `.*`)